# Trying to get data off busted ide drive

Tags: hard-drive, safe-mode, pata

I have an old IDE drive that is getting corruption errors and will not boot in its own box. I can boot safely in safe mode with command prompt. I decided to move the drive out into my own box. I cannot get a boot option for it and it does not show up in my computer. Any ideas how to get get it to work on my own box.

My idea is to run command prompt and copy the files over to my own drives. Its not that much information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I recover a crashed hard drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/155630/how-can-i-recover-a-crashed-hard-drive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, DON'T BOOT TO IT AGAIN, make it a secondary drive. Second, if you can, put only that drive and another empty drive into the computer, and see if you can image it. That is the best way to do it.

If you cannot do that, still make it a secondary drive (like a D drive) to the good, bootable one in your system or another system, and then copy the data.

Every time you boot into it, you risk never having another shot at that data, since booting it is a lot more access intensive than just accessing it as a secondary drive.

If your system already can't see it, it is probably too late due to those extra boots unless you hire professional recovery experts.

Comment: Even when in command prompt and looking for file it doesn't give me anything anywhere...

Comment: @harper89 That is why you ALWAYS clone a failing drive if possible, preferably sector-by-sector. After that, no matter how screwed up the file system is, you can run any tool against it. At that point, you can try chkdsk /f or /r, you can use tools like File Scavenger to extract files from the drive even it the FAT is corrupted.

Comment: No chance wasn't my drive. This is why you ALWAYS back up your files to begin with. We will see what I can pull off

Comment: @harper89 Good luck....fingers crossed.

Comment: Thanks again for the tips. Nothing was saved and it won't even hold a new format says there's no space. Poor things seen its day. Another one bites the dust.